# Is it possible to web scrape with AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, meteor, web-scraping

I'm trying to access a table online inside of my meteor-angular app. The table on the website looks like this:

```
<table class="Grid GridBrowse">
<tbody>
<tr class="GRH">

    //one of the items
<tr>
    <td><a class="ItmTLnk" href="itemLink">ITEM ID</a></td>
    <td>
        <a class="tn1"href="itemLink"><img alt="" src="http://someLink.com/thumb.jpg" /></a>
    </td>
    <td class="ttC">
        <div>
            <a href="itemLink" class="BItmTLnk">ITEM TITLE</a>
        </div>

    </td>
    <td class="lrt">ITEM PRICE</td>
</tr>
    //end item
</tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle of Table](http://jsfiddle.net/hetman/6d7tq5tw/)

There are multiple `<td>` items in the table that all look like the one in the fiddle, all have the same class names. I need to iterate over them in order to get to the Item ID, image, title, and price.

How can I pull in this table and then iterate over it to get these elements?

Comment: The correct link is: http://jsfiddle.net/hetman/6d7tq5tw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking just requires standard Javascript.  Try this.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ItmTLnk');
```

You'll end up with an array of the matching elements and have access to the element properties.

Comment: Thank you Darryl, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You may want to reword your question so that the hold is removed.